# Using html5 <video> tag to let the video pause when clicking next in BXSLIDER

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Isn't there a simple code that pauses the HTML 5 video when you click on a next button? It is very hard to find on Google, I searched and found nothing, or found something but then it didn't work.

I use bxslider for a client in the about page https://www.gester.nl/mbarara/about. Scroll down to see the videoslider. So like I said above the problem is when I click arrownext the previous video keeps playing as you can hear.

This is my code:

```
<h1> Choose between 8 video's </h1>


<!-- VIDEO PLUGIN -->

<ul class="videoslider">
  <li>
    <div id="content">
      <video class="myvideo" controls >
        <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
      </video>
    </div>
    <div id="videocover"></div>
    <div class="overlay">

      <pppp>Video number 1</pppp>
      <pp>Swipe or touch left/right arrow</pp>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <video class="myvideo1" controls>
      <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">      
    </video>
    <div id="videocover1"></div>
    <div class="overlay">

      <pppp>Video number 2</pppp>
      <pp>Swipe or touch left/right arrow</pp>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

And these are my controls from bxslider:

```
/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
  left: 10px;
  background: url(../images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev:focus {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
  right: 10px;
  background: url(../images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-next:focus {
  background-position: -43px 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  outline: 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
   z-index: 9999;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This question is likely saved from closure by the presence of code, but it's probably worth pointing out that we like questions to be self-contained here. That means that if an external link becomes unavailable in the future, the question still makes sense and does not have to be deleted. Worth a read: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script pauses all videos on click of a slider arrow (I tested it on your site via the console.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".bx-controls-direction a").on("click",function(){
    // pause all videos.
    $(".videoslider").find("video").each(function(){
      $(this)[0].pause();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Heey @LouysPatriceBessette , thanks for solving this for me. It worked perfectly. Thanks for your time and i wish you a nice day!

Greetings,

Gester

Comment: It works good on a apple device and it works good on an Samsung device but not if i swipe the video to the left then the first video keeps playing. Is there a simple way for you to make a code that also let the video pause when you swipe instead of using ".bx-controls-direction a" for the Samsung phone?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: For the swipes... You should use `onSlideBefore` callback in the bx-slider options. like: `onSlideBefore: function(){$(".videoslider").find("video").each(function(){
      $(this)[0].pause();
    }); } ` See [documentation](http://bxslider.com/options)